# How to check for Proximity Alerts and find them

Tags: android, proximity

I have a question regarding proximity alerts. 
In all tutorials I ve read they are created and destroyed while the activity that create them is still running. 
But what happens if say an activity creates n proximity alerts and then the activity itself is destroyed (the PA are not)

Then if I want to build another activity that finds these Proximity Alerts, how can I do that? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, all proximity alerts need a `PendingIntent` defined and used as a parameter. [Android's Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) shows that if you know the list of `PendingIntent`s then you can remove them as well.

> removeProximityAlert(PendingIntent intent) Removes the proximity alert
>   with the given PendingIntent.

Since `PendingIntent` is `Parecelable` [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) then you could add it as an `Extra` to any `Intent`. This means, that on starting another Activity, you can create an `Parcelable[]` array to hold all these `PendingIntent`, then

> putExtra(String name, Parcelable[] value)
>   Add extended data to the intent.

then retrieve them in the next Activity via `getIntent()` and it's relevant methods.

Comment: Thank you. From what you explained I get that that is if I the PA were created in Activity A, and then Activity B is called from Activity A, later the PA destroyed by Activity B, right? In other words, there is a transition from Act A to Act B, am I wrong?  I was meaning more in the sense that Act A and Act B are unrelated...

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain your own list of proximity alerts. There is no way to get them back. However, @Mercato is correct when he says that you can remove a PA using only pending intents, but you don't have to store them. According to the docs:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

This means that the system will store your [`PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for you between app restarts, and you can retrieve it by passing the same [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you used to create it. So for example, if you created the following `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Foo.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then all you have to store is the `requestId` (1) and the `Class` or class name (`Foo.class` or `Foo.class.getName()`). Then if you want to retrieve that same `PendingIntent` without creating a new one, you can do the following:

```
Class<Foo> className = retrieveClass(); //You implement this
//String clazz = retrieveClassName(); //This is another option
int requestId = retrieveId(); //You implement this

Intent intent = new Intent(context, className);

//The flag given attempts to retrieve the PendingIntent if it exists, returns null if it doesn't.
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pi != null) {
    //This pending intent was registered once before. 
    //Go ahead and call the function to remove the PA. Also, go ahead and call pi.cancel() on this.
}
else {
    //This pending intent was not registered, and therefore can't have a PA registered to it. 
}
```

Comment: Very nice thank you! I understood your explanation, I just have one question. The documentation says "..same flags" but in the code the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT has been replaced by FLAG_NO_CREATE. I think that makes sense but doesn't it contradict the documentation?

Comment: I believe you are talking about the intent passed into the pendingintent, which would make a difference. The `FLAG_NO_CREATE` is a pendingintent flag that notifies the OS not to create a new pendingintent. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will either update the pendingintent with new extras given in your intent as long as that intent is equal to the old one, or create a new pendingintent.